# PHP Mysqli, making PHP use the latest connection automatically instead of having to indicate the mysql connection link resource

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I just converted from `mysql` to `mysqli` api on PHP...

i noticed that some mysql calls require `$connection` resource parameter to be indicated, w/c i found quite annoying latey as i tried to port my scripts to this new API... is there a way i can configure PHP to use the latest connection resource automatically instead of having to decalre it every single time i make these calls? - kinda like the behaviour of the old `mysql` API..

I do hope there is a switch or something for this.

Comment: Object oriented style is probably what you are looking for.

Comment: You can migrate your php application from mysql to mysqli within 2 minutes by using mysql's best 'The MySQL ext/mysql Converter Tool' [http://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/Contrib/mysqli_converter/mysqli_converter-1.0.zip/from/pick](http://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/Contrib/mysqli_converter/mysqli_converter-1.0.zip%20/from/pick) This tool provides both GUI and CLI interface to intreact it. You can pass your single or multiple php files.It will analyze your php source code and search all your mysql expressions in your php files and replace them with latest mysqli expressions as you want.
Thanks.

Comment: i chose to stick w/ procedural.. i find it faster and more convinient to code.. i mean if i have to do an object declaration and stuff every single time, i might as well just pass the darn resource link w/ procedural queries hehe

Comment: page not available.. also thanks but i dont think that will be 100% compatible w/ my project.. i believe it's far too complex for any script to "analyze and convert 100%" .. i basically built my own frameworks and now im having to crawl through all the mysql calls and globalize into the functions and methods the $connection variable.. such a hassle

Comment: @BrownChiLD Link fixed.

Comment: https://wikis.oracle.com/display/mysql/Converting+to+MySQLi

Comment: Implicit connection sharing is actually a *really bad practice*, which is why the newer extensions don't support it. To keep your code sane and long term maintainable you *should* explicitly pass the connection variable around; you *should* have done this with old mysql too. mysqli and PDO simply make it mandatory. Given this, if you think the object oriented style is more complicated, you do not understand it.

Comment: bad practice shmactise. lol. it works! it has worked for YEARS..there's virtually no security flaw w/ this technique as far as the way i use it, and the only inconvenience is if i have to connect to 2 different DBs in 1 script, that's when i have to explicitly declare the connection resources, w/c i dont mind doing ever so RARELY, instead of now i have to do it ALL THE FREAKING TIME. and no OOP way of this doesnt make coding shorter, just look at the examples of oop vs procedural. often times you'l see more lines and chars of code w/ OOP. PS, i love OOP and i use it a lot-but not in everything

Answer (score 1):

Nope, there is no [sane] way.

But that's not the problem.
The point is that switching to mysqli mechanically makes no sense.

The only reason for moving from mysql to mysqli is **prepared statements**.
If you aren't going to use them, and if you want to stick with raw API methods which require repeating the same useless 4-6 lines of code for the every query, without using any abstraction (which will reduce that amount to 1-2 lines) - there is no point in switching drivers then. Keep on with old mysql. 5.5 is no out yet and 5.4 is still rarely available on shared hostings. Means you have 5-6 years ahead for your old code to run with no problem.

Comment: well i was thinking about not switching, but i have several projects in line and i wana start developing on an updated framework of mine .. hence i wanted to do early adoption of the new standard mysql API .. tnx for your input